# mongodb get index of an array item from another array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

If documents in a collection are:

```
{array1: ["a", "b", "c"]},
{array2: ["c", "a", "b"]}
```

I want to find the index of "the element of array2" in array1 in the aggregation pipeline, the output should be like [2, 0, 1], because the index of the first element in array2 is "c", and the index of "c" in array1 is 2.

The original use of indexOfArray is:

```
{$indexOfArray: [ "$array", "a" ] }
```

where "a" is a specified value, is there any way can find the index of an item, and the item is from another array in the same collection?

something like

```
{$indexOfArray: [ "$array1", "every item in array2" ] }
```

Comment: If posting _code_ please use the style options in the editor. This makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking but the content given appears to be "two documents". You cannot "practically" use the aggregation framework to compare values in "different documents" without coercing them into a "single document". Your question would be better if instead of an "abstract case" you actually presented what you "really need to do" instead, as we can then clearly show what a "real solution" is. If these are indeed "two documents" or "multiple documents", then present "that" case. If you just got it wrong and it's "one document" then please edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: sorry, I mean two documents in the same collection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use javascript instead of aggregation.
Suppose the collection **TestArray** has following two documents.

```
{ "arr1" : [ "a", "b", "c" ], "arr2" : [ "c", "a", "b" , "x","y" ] }
{ "arr1" : [ "a", "b", "c" ], "arr2" : [ "c", "a", "b" ] }
```

The output for the first document should be [ 2, 0, 1, -1, -1 ], where -1 represents elements in arr2 at respective index were not found in arr1.
The output for the second document should be [ 2, 0, 1].
Below mentioned code would give the result.

```
db.TestArray.find({}).forEach(function(obj){var arr = [] ; src = obj.arr2 ; des = obj.arr1 ; for(var i=0 ; i<src.length ; i++){arr.push(des.indexOf(src[i]));};printjson(arr)}
```

You could provide filter conditions in the find operation to limit the rows that qualify for the current operation.